# actual work hours larger than plan work hours in microsoft project

Tags: ms-project

I update my project actual work hour every week.But if actual  work hours larger than plan  work hours,the plan  work hours is changed to equal to actual work hour automatic.Is there any way that  actual  work hours larger than plan  work in ms project?

Answer (score 1):

No, estimated work is always greater or equal to actual work and remaining work is always greater or equal to zero.

You can for example use baselines to store history of changes in Estimation.